# How to give all controls inside table a specific style

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this

```
<table class="row col-lg-offset-1 thumbnail">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2">First Name</td>
        <td class="col-lg-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2">Last Name</td>
        <td class="col-lg-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2">E-Mail</td>
        <td class="col-lg-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" CssClass="form-control form-group" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to give each control inside td a specific style. In this case the Asp:TextBox and Asp:Button.
How do i write the css in this case.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Thanx for the response all of you.

Answer (score 1):

I see CSS-classes - use it

```
.form-control {
    ...
}
.form-control {
    ...
}
.btn {
    ...
}
```

or add your owns

Answer (score 0):

For the textboxes

```
table input[type="text"]{
}
```

for the buttons

```
table input[type="submit"]{
}
```

Or just give each tr it's own ID and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you maintained class for all inner elements.

```
table .form-control {
    //Your rule for input fields
}
table .btn {
    //Your rule for button
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted only this specific table to be styled. And all others must not acquire the style.

Comment: then add a specific class(say "my-table") to that table and change your css with

.my-table .form-control {
    //Your rule for input fields
}
.my-table .btn {
    //Your rule for button
}

Comment: Ohh like that. Ok lemme check it and get back to you. Thanx for response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style for all your form fields with the 'form-control' class

```
.form-control {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
  // etc
}
```

If you want to change the style for a specific field, you can use the ID attribute as a selector, e.g., for the Email field in your code:

```
#TextBox5 {
  color:#fff;
  // etc
}
```

For your buttons, you've got a btn class right there, so

```
.btn { 
  border:3px solid red;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:7px;
  // etc
}
```